# docker-compose django mysql with .env: can't connect to mysql server error

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mysql-python

## dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /django_app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ADD . /django_app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /django_app
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    hostname: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3308:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
       MYSQL_USER : 'mysqluser'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root123'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root123'
    # volumes:
    #   - D:\django_project\db1:/var/run/mysqld
    #   - D:\django_project\db:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure  
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "NAME": 'test',
        "USER": 'mysqluser',
        "PASSWORD": 'root123',
        "HOST": 'db',
        "PORT": 3306,
    }
}
```

[image: error 1.]

error 2

[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')) #0 81.18 #0 91.27 WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip. failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1

Django container cannot connect to MySql container.

Comment: Please show settings.py part related to DB connection

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Is the error message longer than what you've rendered into that PNG attachment; is it a "connection refused" error, "no such host", authentication, something else?  It also looks like your Dockerfile might be missing its `CMD` line at the end.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "NAME": 'test',
        "USER": 'mysqluser',
        "PASSWORD": 'root123',
        "HOST": 'db',
        "PORT": 3306,
    }
}